# Random Div Block Background Metro Style

Tags: jquery, random

The situation is i have div blocks.. imagine the windows 8 metro style.
i wanted to have an array of colors, and each time i reload the page,
the color of the blocks changes.

i have created a simple random script using jquery, but once the page loads, the blocks are in the same color.. here is my code

```
$('#block').css('background', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]);
```

what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) method. Try this

```
$(function(){
    var colors = ["red","green","blue","yellow"];

    setInterval(function() {
           $('#block').css('background', colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
    }, 500);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rU8DA/4/)**

To get color code randomly without using array of color. You can generate dynamically hexadecimal value for color codes.

```
$('#block').css('background', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
```

In terms of multiple div block try below code :

```
$(function(){
   $("div").each(function(){
      $(this).css('background','#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
   });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rU8DA/17/)**

Good Luck !!

Comment: i think this is not what i am looking for... but thanks really!!

Comment: if i have multiple div blocks, your code will show me similar colors on the blocks... which i dont want.

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito, i have modified my answer. is this you are looking for?